# Pyspark filter on array of structs

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I've a pyspark dataframe with below schema:

```
root
 |-- channelGrouping: string (nullable = false)
 |-- clientId: string (nullable = false)
 |-- customDimensions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to fetch all those records for which the index "2" of customDimensions matches regular expression r'b'.

Sample Input

```
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+
|clientId|channelGrouping| customDimensions         |                                                                                                             
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+
|  123   |  alpha        | [[1, a], [2, b]          |
|  456   |  beta         | [[1, a], [2, b], [3, c]  |
|  789   |  gama         | [[1, a], [2, a], [3, c]  |
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+
|clientId|channelGrouping| customDimensions         |                                                                                                             
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+
|  123   |  alpha        | [[1, a], [2, b]          |
|  456   |  beta         | [[1, a], [2, b], [3, c]  |
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

In bigquery this can be achieved using below query:

select
*
from
`some_table`
where
REGEXP_CONTAINS((SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=2), r'b')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to write a solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.json("some_path")

df1 = df.where(element_at(map_from_entries(col("customDimensions")), 2).rlike('b'))
```